# How can I fix my problem with r.id for android?

Tags: eclipse, togglebutton

Hi I'm really new to android coding and app development and I need some help with this please!

Here's my situation:
I'm using app development for dummies and it gives me the code to write for the app, the problem start with *findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);* there is an error under R.id.
I keep getting this same error no matter what I try. The quick fixes that it shows are *(create field 'id' in type 'R')* or *(create constant 'id' in type 'R')*

It doesn't make any sense to me because in my main.xml file I  have the id *android:id="@+id/toggleButton"*

Any help is very much appreciated! =)

Answer (score 0):

When you compile in Eclipse, it should create R.java file automatically for you that is used to identify the resources.  You should see +gen ( Generated Java File ) in your project tree once you have it successfully built.  You might want to build it, before referencing it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your onCreate method and make sure that you have the following line `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. This line states which xml file is being accessed. Also make sure that you have imported the R to your project, hovering over it should provide the option to import it. If both of these tips do not work; go to build and clean project and it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open java build path and check version 2.2(5.5) or whatever available